# Start MyConsoleApp vs Start Cmd /C MyConsoleApp - Any Difference?

Tags: shell, cmd.exe

As per the title, what is the difference between

- start MyConsoleApp
- start cmd /C MyConsoleApp

The exhibited behavior appears exactly the same, both launch a new cmd prompt, run myConsoleAPp, then close the new cmd prompt;

What are the use-cases for using first version vs second version?

Comment: As the question is about specifics and use cases for launching a .NET project tool, I'd suggest asking in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead. Questions related to coding and coding tools are [off topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) in SuperUser.

Comment: @Peregrino69 where does .NET come into it? the question is about the command line (also known as command prompt or shell)  in Windows; MyConsoleApp is just an example executable file, it could be replaced with ping.exe or netsh.exe or whatever you want !